# SAPUI5 Master page overflow on icontab while maximize window

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am developing application[SAPUI5].Which is master-detail based Application.I am facing problem in internet explorer while maximize the size of window,My contents of page not becoming original size.

```
var resizeListener = function(){
      $(window).one("resize",function(){ //unbinds itself every time it fires
          if(scroll_ID != undefined){
              var footerHeight = window.innerHeight - thatDetail.byId("SplitMasterFooterid").getDomRef().getBoundingClientRect().top;
              var tablePositionTop = thatDetail.byId(scroll_ID).getDomRef().getBoundingClientRect().top;
              var scrollHeight = window.innerHeight - footerHeight - tablePositionTop - 20; 
              thatDetail.byId(scroll_ID).setHeight(String(scrollHeight + "px"));  
        }         
        //resize things
        setTimeout(resizeListener,100); //rebinds itself after 100ms
      });
    }
    resizeListener();
```

thank you.please help me out of this issue

Comment: anyone having idea regarding this issue?